# input:valid not working - not focusing yet, but label is already on top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to avoid label from going back to its initial position (if unfocus) whenever there is some text in the input field, [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLXbKg) it's working fine.

But in my other [code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvYVLx), it's not working, I'm not focusing yet, but label is already on top:

```
input:focus + label > span,
input:valid + label > span {
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be that, in your second piece of code, the `username` text stays in the text input. Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: you forgot to separate selectors with comma

Comment: @ChrisLi fixed.

Comment: @JBDouble05 no, I forgot to add comma to separate selectors, now label is already on top even though not yet focus..

Comment: You have set a default margin-top: -33px; to the span which moves it outside the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why, you need attribute required in the input
like this `<input type="text" name="name" class="input-field" id="user" required/>`
using :valid on input will select input that is validated, if you have required on the input but it's empty, it's not validated and the style won't take effect.
read more about :valid here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid